# 'Preview Component' feature not working when using the JetBrains plugin 'React Buddy'

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I recently tried to do my react development using 'React buddy' plugin in IntelliJ IDEA. There is a cool feature for previewing each component inside the IDE. But it doesn't load.

[image]It keeps loading the dev server but not displaying the preview of the component .

Comment: It is worth submitting an issue to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RCB and providing the logs there (Help > Collect logs and diagnostic data).